# Open app from Mail Client, Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-8

I tried to open application from e-mail client, using Uri associations.I send on my mail link like:

> my_app_name://open_notes_document?replica_id=C12577A8:004C4562&document_id=A5928B700D8194B6C1257D3900371A56

than register my_app_name as it describes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Fileassociations). But when I tap on link in my mail, nothing happens. 
Do anyone open application form e-mail client, and know how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> my_app_name://

You don't need the `//` part, it should be `my_app_name:`

Did you correctly add the following line in your WMAppManifest.xml ?

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="myAppName" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Also, please keep in mind that this will not work from internet explorer until you wrap with the link tag.

`<a href="myAppName:someIdentifier?">my app link</a>`

Otherwise, you should be fine by using the following line to test from another application :

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("myAppName:someIdentifier?"));
```

Comment: It works, when I open app from another app (like this Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("myAppName://someIdentifier?")), and path with // also works. But wen I send link via e-mail, app does not open.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. Problem was in device, because my code did not work for **Nokia Lumia 925** (Windows Phone 8.1) . When I change device for **Nokia Lumia 920** (Windows Phone 8.1) - everything start to work. If someone have same problem as me - try to change device.

Comment: Are you certain that your test devices are using the same version of the OS? I'd be surprised if there were functional differences between different devices using the same build of the operating system. I would recommend testing it on the emulators to ensure it works on WP 8.1 and WP 8.1 Update 1, and on WP 8.0 Update 3 if you're targeting WP 8.0 as well.